# button click to different activity depending upon cases

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

i have static page for no internet connection....this i have to use in two actvity....the static page for no internet connection has tap to retry button...

on that tap to retry button i have to go different activity

scenerio:---------
1.when im splash activity(no internet) ---> it should load homeactvivity

2.when im contact us activity(no internet) ---> it should load contact us activity

need help how to do it???

i have got suggestion like Use some flag like isFromSplash of Boolean type which will be true when nav from splash and false when contact us...

how should i implement??????

```
    binding.btnTaptoretry.setOnClickListener {
        if (this.isDeviceOnlineStatus(this)){
            if (isFromSplash==true) { //this is red `isFromSplash`
                val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
            else{
                val intent = Intent(this, AboutUsActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()   
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It completely depends how you've constructed underlying activity navigation and data flow. I usually prefer one fragment that is added to activities when there's no internet and then I can decide from there about current activity and provide callback to it for navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splash Activity.Java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static com.saqib.app2.RetryActivity.SOURCE;
import static com.saqib.app2.RetryActivity.SPLASH;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(!Utils.isInternetConnection(this)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RetryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(SOURCE, SPLASH);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Contact activity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static com.saqib.app2.RetryActivity.CONTACT;
import static com.saqib.app2.RetryActivity.SOURCE;
import static com.saqib.app2.RetryActivity.SPLASH;

public class ContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!Utils.isInternetConnection(this)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ContactActivity.this, RetryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(SOURCE, CONTACT);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
    }
}
```

Utils.Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class Utils {

    public static boolean isInternetConnection(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        return isConnected;
    }
}
```

RetryActivity.java (for retry to go to specified activity)

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class RetryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SPLASH = "SPLASH";
    public static final String CONTACT = "CONTACT";
    public static final String SOURCE = "SOURCE";
    Button btnRetry;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retry);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String source = intent.getExtras().getString(SOURCE);
        btnRetry = findViewById(R.id.btnRetry);
        btnRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(Utils.isInternetConnection(RetryActivity.this)) {
                    switch (source) {
                        case SPLASH:
                            startActivity(new Intent(RetryActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
                            finish();
                            break;
                        case CONTACT:
                            startActivity(new Intent(RetryActivity.this, ContactActivity.class));
                            finish();
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Used Intent to send data and receive either it comes from splash or contact.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 final String source = intent.getExtras().getString(SOURCE);
```

This is the magic from where get the history. From where it came.

Comment: @IRON MAN have you checked it ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

```
lateinit var button : Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
    button.setOnClickListener(listener)
}

val listener= View.OnClickListener { view ->
    when (view.getId()) {
        if(view.getid == R.id.button1)-> {
            // Do some work here
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: no....i have static nointernet activity there i have taptoretry button

Comment: where you are checking. It is coming from which acitivity?

Comment: @HaseebMirza can you help?

Comment: let me make a logic of it

Comment: @HaseebMirza have you make logic?

Comment: I have make sample project. I will share the link.

Comment: @HaseebMirza where is the link i cant see it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J99FU56ai1KB_CCDjz_yEC7871cPzytV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @HaseebMirza if this is not wokring then apply switch